# How do I capture snapshots of the video output of a specific process with DirectX?

Tags: c#, directx

I'm currently using the `SharpDX.Direct3D11` NuGet package to capture the entire screen and transform it into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object, like so:

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;
using MapFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags;
using Resource = SharpDX.DXGI.Resource;

public class Direct3D11CaptureSource : SyncDisposable, ICaptureSource
{
    public Direct3D11CaptureSource()
    {
        factory = new Factory1();
        adapter = factory.GetAdapter1(0);
        device = new Device(adapter);
        output = adapter.GetOutput(0);
        var desktopBounds = output.Description.DesktopBounds;
        width = desktopBounds.Right - desktopBounds.Left;
        height = desktopBounds.Bottom - desktopBounds.Top;
        output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>();
        copiedScreenTexture = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription
        {
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
            Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            MipLevels = 1,
            ArraySize = 1,
            SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging
        });
        outputDuplication = output1.DuplicateOutput(device);
        AcquireNextFrame();
        ReleaseFrame();
    }

    readonly Adapter1 adapter;
    readonly Texture2D copiedScreenTexture;
    readonly Device device;
    readonly Factory1 factory;
    readonly int height;
    readonly Output output;
    readonly Output1 output1;
    readonly OutputDuplication outputDuplication;
    Resource screenResource;
    readonly int width;

    void AcquireNextFrame()
    {
        var result = outputDuplication.TryAcquireNextFrame(10000, out _, out screenResource);
        if (result.Failure)
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(outputDuplication.TryAcquireNextFrame)} failed");
        if (!result.Success)
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(outputDuplication.TryAcquireNextFrame)} did not succeed");
    }

    public Bitmap Capture()
    {
        try
        {
            AcquireNextFrame();
            using (var screenTexture = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
                device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture, copiedScreenTexture);
            var map = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(copiedScreenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var bitmapAccess = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            var source = map.DataPointer;
            var target = bitmapAccess.Scan0;
            for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                Utilities.CopyMemory(target, source, width * 4);
                source = IntPtr.Add(source, map.RowPitch);
                target = IntPtr.Add(target, bitmapAccess.Stride);
            }
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapAccess);
            device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(copiedScreenTexture, 0);
            return bitmap;
        }
        finally
        {
            ReleaseFrame();
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ReleaseFrame();
            outputDuplication.Dispose();
            copiedScreenTexture.Dispose();
            output1.Dispose();
            output.Dispose();
            device.Dispose();
            adapter.Dispose();
            factory.Dispose();
        }
    }

    void ReleaseFrame()
    {
        screenResource?.Dispose();
        screenResource = null;
    }
}
```

My goal is more specific though. I'm trying to capture snapshots only from a particular process, specifically a 3D video game. Can I use this NuGet in another way to achieve that? Should I be using another tool?

Comment: You'll need to hook (inject dll) into DirectX calls of the game in order to intercept them and capture the game's back buffer. Some (most) games however, are protected from hooking via dll injection.